# Pandas DataFrame count number of not None elements in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and want to count those rows which are not None in two (or more) different columns simultaneously. Of course I can do it like that:

```
 count = 0
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
      if df['Col1'][index] is not None and
         PurpsAndBanks['Col2'][index] is not None:
         count+=1
```

But is there a more elegant/effiecient approach?

Comment: Use `df['new'] = df.count(axis=1)` ?

Comment: Are these numeric columns, strings, or something else? Is Boolean testing sufficient, e.g. you don't want to count empty strings, `0` or `False` ?

Comment: @jpp arbitrary columns. The content of the rows is not important only if there is something in them or not

Comment: So does `NaN` or `NaT` count as `None` ? If they do, use @jezrael's solution.